# Does the linker in VC2008 has problem with spaces in paths?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, linker, visual-c++

the previous question I asked was about how can I use .lib file with a VC2008 project and the answers were very useful.Now another problem has crept in--for eg. my .h and .lib files are in the folder **c:\pcm**.I specify this path at the required places(c/c++->additional include directories,linker->input->additional dependencies).Every thing works fine.

but when I change the path to **"c:\pc m"**(notice the space) and reflect this change at required places:linker->input and additional include directories etc.

Now on building I get: **Error1 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\pc.obj'**

what's the solution to this problem??

thanks.

Comment: I dunno but this is almost 2011. Why are you breaking the modern separation of system/program/user files by storing things in paths relative to `"c:\"` rather than your home directory?

Comment: it's just an example,actually lib is in:"C:\Users\ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VC++\DataStructures\Debug",additional dependencies=$(OutDir)LinkList.lib.As you can see the 'space' after '\Visual' is creating the problem.

Comment: Actual error was : cannot open file 'C:\Users\ryan\Documents\Visual.obj'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearly universal answer to problems with spaces in path/file names:

- put the path/file name in quotes.

Note that this works even if you're using a VS macro for as part of the name:

```
"$(OutDir)\foo.lib"
```

works (while without quotes it breaks due to spaces in the `$(OutDir)` macro).

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any problem related to this.

Comment: I now use Visual Studio 2010 but used 2008 for several years. Every single time I compiled, there were spaces in the paths because my dev directory had spaces. And I never once had this issue. So, I used the IDE for projects, etc. But all I can say is you've done something that is causing the problem: not enclosing paths in quotes or something like that. But I can pretty much guarantee this is not a linker issue.

Comment: some properties in VS handle unquoted spaces fine, but some don't. "Linker/General/Output File" handles unquoted paths with spaces just fine, but "Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies" doesn't (maybe because it can have multiple values). In any case, the general first step to try to solve a problem with paths that have spaces is to see if slapping some quotes around it helps.

Comment: @"Michael Burr"-thanks man you're right,"linker/input/additional dependencies/" doesn't en-quote the path automatically,after putting the quotes the problem is solved.thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using double quotes around path names is wise.  It is *required* when they contain spaces.  Post the compile command line you find in buildlog.htm if that doesn't help.